# how can I carry on doing heavy bench presses for a long time?

Tags: weightlifting, injury, health, bench-press, freeweights

I do bench press twice a week. Tuesdays and Fridays.

every week I do 180 Kg.

I have been doing this for months now.
OK I cycle every 6 weeks how I get to 90% or 100% but I keep it high.

Sometimes things happen, like the other day my son woke up many times during the night, and daddy needed to take care of him... can't expect the best bench, still we manage to go.

And before this I was doing it once a week, very difficult to miss one week.

Here is a [video of me lifting 200 Kg (440 lbs)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avAI7w4aQDU) for illustration purposes only.

and here are 2 pins I have on my left shoulder due to a motorcycle accident in 2012.
[image]

I have recently changed the bench press position from ["bodybuilder"](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BBBenchPress.html) to ["powerlifter"](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BBBenchPressPowerLift.html) because of inflammation and pain on my chest tendon.

This has really helped a lot the chest tendon, but it takes some time to get used to it.

what can I do to maintain this level of training with the possibility in due course to try new PBs (personal bests) once in a while?

I asked my doctor, he says the chest tendon can snap without a warning when submitted to heavy weights.

I take vitamins and supplements,

try not to get too stressed at work,

try to have minimum sleep,

I am vegetarian, and try to keep a good diet (though I am a bit on the overweight side now).

Comment: That "bodybuilder" bench press is just a regular bench press and what that site is calling a "powerlifter" bench press is just a close-grip bench press. No actual powerlifter would do a close-grip bench press in a powerlifting competition though they may use it for training, but so would a bodybuilder.

Comment: @DavidTheWin with all respect, powerlifter bench press is not just a close-grip bench press

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you and that site called it a "powerlifter" bench press but that video was just a close grip bench press.

Comment: haha I see what you mean, here is a more detailed video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_V189hK85BI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, all I can recommend in your case is to look into Bands. Here is a link to T Nation website. I hope this can help you out.

https://www.t-nation.com/training/bands-for-size-and-strength

Comment: +1 and I have been [using it with great results](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/40276/18296)