# giving the left shoulder a rest. can I train squats and\or the right arm?

Tags: exercise, squats, shoulders, bench-press, arms

Despite being [cautious with the bench press](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/40276/18296) I noticed I feel my left shoulder a bit more when I do [reverse grip lat pull down](https://weighttraining.guide/exercises/reverse-grip-lat-pull-down/) as per the picture below.

[image]

I was considering training the right arms and\or squats, in order to give the left shoulder a rest.

can I still have benefits buy training only the right side plus squats?

where can I see more about this?

Comment: With regards to existing injuries, we really have no way of providing solid advice unless you provide us with scans of the injured area. We may give advice that only worsens the injury. You should see a doctor.

Comment: @alec I have changed the question, removing any indication of `injuries`

Comment: The question is still centered around an injury, but since it opens up the possibility to discuss the benefits/drawbacks of unilateral training, I'll allow it. Keep in mind, the bottom line would still be the same as if it were closed. You must see a doctor before doing any weight training with a shoulder injury. Any advice to the contrary is simply irresponsible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I still have benefits buy training only the right side plus squats?

Let's first deal with the question of only training the right side.

I would heavily caution **against** training one side more than the other side. This would be a surefire way to develop muscular imbalances which cause chronic injuries and pain down the line. Training should always be done equally on both sides.

For the question of squats; yes and no.

Yes, there are benefits to be had by doing squats while your upper body is injured, **BUT**, and this is a very serious **but**: You MUST confer with a physician before doing so. The reason for this is that we don't know if loading the bar onto your shoulders is going to worsen the shoulder injury you have. And it's very likely that it will. The same also goes for other exercises like deadlifts, because also there the weight is loaded onto your shoulders (via the arms).

Due to the ambiguity of knowing there's an injury present, but not knowing enough about it, the answer can only be: Go see a doctor before doing any sort of weight training.